# Is there a way to STOP not TERMINATE instances using auto-scaling in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am looking at using AWS auto-scaling to scale my infrastructure up and down based on various performance metrics (CPU, etc.). I understand how to set this up; however, I don't like that instances are terminated rather than stopped when it is scaled down. This means that when I scale back up, I have to start from scratch with a new instance and re-install my software, etc. I'd rather just start/stop my instances as needed rather than create/terminate. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Most use cases for autoscaling follow that the needed software is either bootstrapped (installed via automation) at startup or pre-baked into the source AMI.  It sounds like you're perhaps using it incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, I can bootstrap it at startup but this will take several minutes given the amount of software and configuration that needs to be done (I have tested this). I guess I could potentially build my own AMI with all of the software already there and configured. I have not tried that yet.

Comment: @user3712321 building your own AMI with everything configured is a standard practice for autoscaling unless you're using Elastic Beanstalk - even then, great starting point.

Comment: Yes, This is what a Warm pool lifecycle is for.  You  can keep preconfigured instances in a warm pool.  Not sure why this isnt really detailed in Johns answer. Look at @mwalling answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, it is not possible to **Stop** an instance under Auto Scaling. When a Scaling Policy triggers the removal of an instance, Auto Scaling **will always Terminate** the instance.

However, here's some ideas to cope with the concept of Termination...

**Option 1: Use pre-configured AMIs**

You can configure an Amazon EC2 instance with your desired software, data and settings. Then, select the EC2 instance in the Management Console and [choose the **Create Image** action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html). This will create a new **Amazon Machine Image (AMI)**. You can then configure Auto Scaling to use this AMI when launching a new instance. Each new instance will contain exactly the same disk contents.

It's worth mentioning that EBS starts up very quickly from an AMI. Instead of copying the whole AMI to the boot disk, it copies it across on "first access". This means the new instance can start-up immediately rather than waiting for the whole disk to be copied.

**Option 2: Use a startup (User Data) script**

Each Amazon EC2 instance has a **User Data** field, which is accessible from the instance. [A script can be passed through the User Data field](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html), which is then executed when the instance starts. The script could be used to install software, download data and configure the instance.

The script could do something very simple, like download a configuration script from a source code repository, then execute the script. This means that machine configuration can be centrally managed and version-controlled. Want to update your app? Just launch a new instance with the updated script and throw away the old instance (which is much easier than "updating" an app).

**Option 3: Add/Remove instances to an Auto Scaling group**

Rather than using Scaling Policies to Launch/Terminate instances for an Auto Scaling group, it is possible to attach/detach specific instances. Thus, you could 'simulate' auto scaling:

- When you want to scale-down, [detach an instance from the Auto Scaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/detach-instance-asg.html), then stop it.
- When you want to add an instance, start the instance then [attach it to the Auto Scaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/attach-instance-asg.html).

This would require your own code, but it is very simple (basically two API calls). You would be responsible for keeping track of which instance to attach/detach.

Comment: Thank you John. Option 2 is not realistic in my case due to the amount of software and configuration that needs to be done for each instance upon startup. However, a pre-configured AMI seems like it will work.

Comment: this answer is not valid as it's from 4 years ago, so please check another one from Noah.

Comment: FYI hashicorp's packer makes baking one's own AMIs very easy and then it can be integrated into a build - change source, jenkins makes a new ami

Comment: Thanks Josh . but what if the instance that i have previously detached is not available ( crashed or terminated ) now I have nothing left to add to auto scaling , what will you do now , basically now er have to tell auto scaling: "my instance has crashed please create new one"

Comment: For those in the future who land here from Google: As of April 2021, Warm Pools can automate option 3. I added documentation excerpts and links to my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71679425/53354

Answer (score 4):

**YES**, it is now possible to STOP not TERMINATE instances using auto-scaling in AWS

Whilst the above answers were no doubt correct at the time of writing, AWS has increased the functionality of ASGs allowing warm pools of instances to be setup

By default these instances start but do not run userdata prior to being stopped and put into the pool, but this too can be allowed.

My scenario was I have multiple servers spread across regions which I use for running dignostics tools in an incident; these servers take up to 45min to build using a userdata script (yes I am going to work on a better deployment mechanism but in the meantime...), 45min is too long to wait in an incident and I don't really want to pay for all the time they will not be in use, which will hopefully be the vast majority of their lives.

I also want to have them automatically rebuilt every x days using the ASG maximum instance lifetime so they never end up running out of date vulnerable AMIs etc

So I created an ASG and set it to:

```
max_size = 1
min_size=0
desired_capacity = 0
```

Next I created a warm pool with the following:

```
Warm pool instance state = stopped
Max warm pool size = 1
Max prepared capacity = 'Equal to ASG max capacity'
```

Then I created a lifecycle hook:

```
Lifecycle transition = 'Instance launch'
Heartbeat timeout = 3600 seconds (if my userdata script takes longer, something has gone wrong)
Default result = 'CONTINUE'
```

To get the instance into the pool without waiting the full hour I added the following to the end of the userdata script, but this is not strictly required:

```
Complete-ASLifecycleAction -AutoScalingGroupName $asg -LifecycleHookName "my_hook_name" -LifecycleActionResult "CONTINUE" -InstanceId $MyInstanceId
```

Finally I set the instance-reuse-policy ReuseOnScaleIn policy to true; at the time of writing this cannot be done via the console and I did all the above via terraform, but it can be done via the CLI:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/examples-warm-pools-aws-cli.html
Again this was optional for my needs and just means when I stop an EC2 it returns to the pool rather than being restarted.

End result - servers managed by an ASG that can enter a stopped state saving me money but which are available in less then 5min when I need them

Comment: Just  used this with a different role and the EC2 stopped immediately after being started (prior to the status checks running)

Turns out that giving the role ec2:StartInstance permission is not sufficient - it also requires kms:CreateGrant access to the key used to setup the EBS storage on the EC2.  There's a few hours I'm not getting back!

AWS docs on the access: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_CreateGrant.html

Answer (score 3):

You can suspend scaling processes, see documentation here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-suspend-resume-processes.html#as-suspend-resume

Comment: Suspending a scaling process refers to suspending the AWS actions as explained in the AWS link above. It DOES NOT suspend your EC2. The answers above are still correct you cannot get AWS auto scaling to STOP instead of TERMINATE your instance.

Comment: @AstroTom If you suspend the termination scaling process then you can stop an instance without it being terminated.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you have three official AWS options to reboot or even stop an instance which belongs to an Auto Scaling Group:

- Put the instance into the Standby state
- Detach the instance from the group
- Suspend the health check process

Ref.: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reboot-autoscaling-group-instance/

Comment: what if your standby ec2 instance has failed , will autoscaling will create new one then ?

Answer (score 1):

Add that instance to Scale in protection and then stop the instance then it will not delete your instance as it's having the scale in protection.

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2021:

**Option 4: Use Warm Pools and an Instance Reuse Policy**

> By default, Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling terminates your instances when your Auto Scaling group scales in. Then, it launches new instances into the warm pool to replace the instances that were terminated.
>
> If you want to return instances to the warm pool instead, you can specify an instance reuse policy. This lets you reuse instances that are already configured to serve application traffic.

This mostly automates [option 3 from John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30497090/53354).

Release announcement: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scaling-your-applications-faster-with-ec2-auto-scaling-warm-pools/

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-warm-pools.html

Answer (score 0):

*This is to expand a little on @mwalling's answer, because that is the right direction, but needs a little extra work to prevent instance termination.*

**There is now a way to stop or hibernate scaled in instances!**
By default AWS Autoscaling scale in policy is to terminate an instance. Even if you have a warm pool configured. Autoscaling will create a fresh instance to put into the warm pool. Presumably to make sure you start with a fresh machine every time. However, with a instance reuse policy you can make AWS Autoscaling either stop or hibernate a running instance and store that instance in the warm pool.

**Advantages include:**

- Local caches stay populated (use hibernate for in memory cache).
- Burstable EC2 instances (those types with T*) keep built up burst credits instead of the newly created instance that have limited or no credits.

**Practical example:**
We use a burstable EC2 instance for CI/CD work that we scale to 0 instances outside working hours. With a reuse policy our local image repository stays populated with the most important Docker images. Also we keep the built up credit from the previous day and that speeds up automatic jobs we run first thing every morning.

**How to implement:**
There's currently no way of doing this completely via the management console. So you will need to use AWS CLI or SDK.

First create a warm pool as described in the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-warm-pools.html#create-a-warm-pool-console)

Then execute this command to add a reuse policy:

```bash
aws autoscaling put-warm-pool --auto-scaling-group-name <Name-of-autoscaling-group> --instance-reuse-policy ReuseOnScaleIn=true
```

Reference docs for the command: [AWS CLI Autoscaling put-warm-pool documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/autoscaling/put-warm-pool.html)

**Flow diagram of possible life cycles of EC2 instances:**
[image: Flow diagram showing how a instance can transition from InService to either terminating or return to a warm pool based on ReuseOnScaleIn configuration]

[Image from AWS Documentation: Lifecycle state transitions for instances in a warm pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/warm-pool-instance-lifecycle.html#lifecycle-state-transitions)