# AWS - EC2 stop instances not working properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm very new on AWS and now I have two EC2 instances. In order to avoid waste the free tier plan I'm trying to stop instances when I'm not working with them.

This is what my EC2 Management console shows. As you can see there are two instances running and two instances terminated. I did not terminate swipe-dev, I have just stop it. But for any reason now is terminated plus new same instance with same source code was started. **Why?**

What I'm doing wrong? I just want stop instances.

[image]

## Edit

I have decide keep just one project so I terminate eb-flask-demo-dev and stop swipe-dev instance. After few minutes instace state was stoped and I thought finally everything is fine. But I rejoin to EC2 console and this is what it shows.
**Why swipe-dev is running again? and Why there is another terminated instance?**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is possible if your instance is a member of an Autoscaling group with desired capacity = 1 and set minimum size to 0. To maintain the number of healthy instances, Auto Scaling performs a periodic health check on running instances within an Auto Scaling group. When it finds that an instance is unhealthy (in this case because you stopped it), it terminates that instance and launches a new one.

Comment: Where can I find what group it belongs? I just follow this tutorial http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-common-steps.html I don't find where can I set autoscaling.

Comment: From EC2 Management Console, at the bottom left menu, there is Autoscaling groups option, check there. If there is a group created, just change desired capacity to zero. (from the first glance at that Beanstalk document, it does look like Autoscaling group is created as part of the process)

Comment: I changed to 0, but still new running instances appearing in instances list.

Comment: set minimum size to 0 also

Comment: I have already tried it. But what I get is a terminated instance. I will read this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingInstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493517/is-there-a-way-to-stop-not-terminate-instances-using-auto-scaling-in-aws