# Can we stop EC2 instance from Auto Scaling Group from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Auto Scaling Group and I want to stop that instance from Auto Scaling Group rather than terminating, Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to STOP not TERMINATE instances using auto-scaling in AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493517/is-there-a-way-to-stop-not-terminate-instances-using-auto-scaling-in-aws)

Answer (score 1):

No. From the official definition:

> Auto Scaling is a web service designed to **launch** or **terminate** Amazon EC2 instances automatically based on user-defined policies, schedules, and health checks.

When scaling-out, new instances are **launched** into the Auto Scaling group.

When scaling-in, instances are **terminated**.

Auto Scaling **does not** start/start instances.

Some benefits of this approach are:

- Instances can be launched in **different Availability Zones** in case there is a failure in a particular AZ
- **Failed instances** can be easily replaced
- There is **no limit** to the number of instances that could be launched (compared to running out of 'stopped' instances)
- **Launch Configurations** can be updated, so any newly-launched instances will use the new configuration (as opposed to recycling old instances)