# I stopped an ec2 instance that was part of an autoscaling group and it was automatically terminated. Am I screwed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

I was having some problems with a slow ec2 instance that I had added autoscaling for and decided to reboot it, which didn't do anything. I decided to stop and restart it. The auto-scaler seems to have picked up on the fact it was stopped and TERMINATED the instance without warning me. I didn't setup anything that would copy data between instances so I am thinking the whole server might be gone?

This is the message I got in ec2 autoscaling groups > activity: "an instance was taken out of service in response to an EC2 health check indicating it has been terminated or stopped."

Comment: Once an EC2 server is terminated, it is "gone". If you were storing critical data on an EC2 instance in an auto-scaling group, the you were definitely using AWS incorrectly. If you weren't taking EBS snapshots of the EC2 instance that contained critical data, then you were also using AWS incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, the a terminated EC2 instance is terminated .. it's gone.  This is probably a good lesson that you should treat EC2 instances as [cattle, not pets](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/653/what-is-the-definition-of-cattle-not-pets).

Comment: Discussion of alternative options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493517).

Comment: Check if you have your EBS volume, you might still have it